# R: Applying a Function to an xts Object

Tags: r, function, date, apply, xts

I have an xts object:

```
Anchor_Date <- as.Date("2016-04-19")
End_Date <- as.Date(Anchor_Date + years(5))
Number_Days <- End_Date - Anchor_Date  
Xts_Object <- xts(rep(NA, Number_Days + 1), as.Date(Anchor_Date) + 0:Number_Days)
```

I also have a function that takes the square of time between a date and a start date in years:

```
Time_Squared_Func <- function(Start_Date, Date) {
  Time_Squared <- as.numeric(((Date - Start_Date) / 365) ^ 2)
  Return (Time_Squared)
}
```

I want to apply the function to the xts object, using a constant Start_Date = the first day in the series, but have the Date argument be the date in that row of the xts object. The result should be 0 in the first row, gradually increasing to 1 on 2017-04-19, 4 on 2018-04-19 etc...

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39180/best-way-to-apply-across-an-xts-object

This suggests that vapply is much faster than apply or lapply, so if possible using vapply would be ideal, but anything working is fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using lapply and rbind

```
require(lubridate)

Anchor_Date <- as.Date("2016-04-19")
End_Date <- as.Date(Anchor_Date + years(5))
Number_Days <- End_Date - Anchor_Date  
Xts_Object <- xts(rep(NA, Number_Days + 1), as.Date(Anchor_Date) +  0:Number_Days)

Time_Squared_Func <- function(Start_Date, Date) {
  Time_Diff = as.numeric(Date - Start_Date)
  Time_Squared <- (Time_Diff / 365) ^ 2
  return (Time_Squared)
}
```

Pass first date and each row index (date) to the Time_Squared_Func function and rbind the output for final result

```
first_date = as.Date(index(first(Xts_Object)))

ts_lapply = do.call(rbind,lapply(as.Date(index(Xts_Object)),function(x) Time_Squared_Func(first_date ,x) ) )

ts_xts = xts(ts_lapply,as.Date(index(Xts_Object)))

for(i in 1:5) print(ts_xts[Anchor_Date+years(i)])
           # [,1]
# 2017-04-19    1
           # [,1]
# 2018-04-19    4
           # [,1]
# 2019-04-19    9
               # [,1]
# 2020-04-19 16.02193
              # [,1]
# 2021-04-19 25.0274
```